# Calculate value of $A_{n}(n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was solving the diffusion equation when you let a drop of ink inside a vertical container of water.Well I have solved the diffusion equation except this part:

Let C(y,t) be the concentration of ink.I applied a boundary condition to a vertical container of 1m length $C(y,0) = \frac{1}{2}\delta(y-1)$ which seems very possible since at $t=0$ the concentration of ink of the container is zero except at the top of the container.

Now by applying the boundary condition to the general form of the solution I am left with this:

$\frac{1}{2} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}sin((n\pi)^{2})$.How can I find $A_{n}$?

Edit:

One of the answer made me realize I need to clarify something:

Here is my full solution so far:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether the solution you are proposing makes sense, since you have chosen the basis of eigenfunctions $\{\sin n\pi x, n>0\}$ and these ensure that the concentration of the liquid is zero at the edges (Dirichlet boundary conditions), but your initial condition does not obey this restriction- in fact your distribution is rendered infinite at $x=1$. Furthermore, Dirichlet BC's do not allow for an appropriate equilibrium distribution at $t\to\infty$.

One possible resolution is to impose Neumann boundary conditions

$$\frac{\partial C}{\partial x}(t,0)=\frac{\partial C}{\partial x}(t,1)=0$$

which allows the concentration to be non-zero at the edges, but it instead ensures that liquid doesn't flow outside the container (the gradient is proportional to the current). The appropriate solution in this case involves cosines instead of sines

$$u(t,x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty A_ne^{-n^2t}\cos n\pi x$$

In order to obtain reasonable results, we need to define a new distribution $\delta_-(x-a)$ which acts on test functions with compact support within a subset of the interval $(-\infty,a)$ with the effect

$$\int_{-\infty}^a\delta_-(x-a)\phi(x)=\frac{1}{2}\phi(a)$$

With these definitions, can you show that the desired solution is

$$A_n=\begin{Bmatrix}\frac{(-1)^n}{4 }&, ~~n>0\\ \frac{1}{2}&,~~ n\neq 0\end{Bmatrix}$$

?

Comment: Actually the Dirichlet boundary conditions are not 0.Let me add the picture to make you understand what I mean .I am solving it in Whiteboard....

Comment: See update of the question....

Comment: The boundary conditions are still incompatible with the initial conditions. $C(0,t)=1/2$ while the initial condition requires $C(0,0)=0$ for example, which contradicts the boundary condition. There are obviously issues on the top of the tube as well.

Comment: Yes I spotted it thanks!

Comment: If you figure out the correct BC's I can change this answer. If it answered your question, don't forget to upvote and accept!